# ref attribute not getting registered in Facebook Insights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using the `put_wall_post` call of the Koala [gem](http://rubydoc.info/github/arsduo/koala/master/Koala/Facebook/GraphAPIMethods#put_wall_post-instance_method) to create notifications on the Facebook walls of an authenticated user's friends. I am also sending a `ref` attribute in the attachment hash which is the second argument to the call, as documented [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/arsduo/koala/master/Koala/Facebook/GraphAPIMethods#put_wall_post-instance_method).

The attachment hash looks something like this:

```
{
  "message"=>"Some random message", 
  "name"=>"Some random name", 
  "description"=>"Some random description", 
  "picture"=>"http://someurl.com/images/some_feed_icon.png", 
  "ref"=>"some_ref"
}
```

But this isn't working - I am not able to see `some_ref` as a Story Type in the Insights Dashboard. Any ideas?

Comment: Neither https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts nor https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ mention a `ref` parameter/attribute for post objects.

Comment: The `ref` parameter was introduced about a year ago in this Facebook [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/528/). It is mentioned a bit further in the post  that the `ref` parameter can also be passed via the Graph API (given the `publish_stream` permission).

Comment: Have you tried to make a post by simple using the Graph API explorer and post with a ref parameter from there? That should tell you if it is working in general, and from that you can conclude if it is a bug of the Koala gem.